# Delete single pixels (noise) from raster

Tags: raster, r, masking

I have a raster layer (based on Landsat (30x30m)) of newly emergent lakes after spring snowmelt and subsequent runoff. These are stored in a raster layer. When I look at it, there is a lot of noise (single pixels) everywhere.
The raster specs are:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 20191, 51818, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0002694946, 0.0002694946  (x, y)
extent      : -122.5147, -108.55, 59.38906, 64.83043  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : dNBR14_02.tif 
name        : lakes 
min value   :   0
max value   :   2
```

I want to delete pixels based on their area and not the values! This means deleting all pixels that cover an area of fewer than two pixels.

[image]

I am using R.

```
library(terra)

lakes = rast('path/lakes.tif')
condition = extent < 2 pixels #How can I set an condition for my masking?
x = mask(lakes, condition, inverse = T)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the recommendation on a sieve approach from terra's help. You can use the `patches`, `zonal` and `ifel` functions to remove pixels base on a criteria such as minimum size.

Read in some data and classify so there are some isolated patches.

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
  r <- classify(r, cbind(-Inf, 400, NA))
```

Remove patches smaller than 100 ha

```
y <- patches(r)
rz <- zonal(cellSize(y, unit="ha"), y, sum, as.raster=TRUE)
  s <- ifel(rz < 100, NA, y)
    plot(c(r,s))
```

Answer (score 0):

This Python utility is made for that purpose https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_sieve.html

> gdal_sieve.py script removes raster polygons smaller than a provided
> threshold size (in pixels) and replaces them with the pixel value of
> the largest neighbour polygon. The result can be written back to the
> existing raster band, or copied into a new file.

The Python source code is in GitHub https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal_sieve.py. Perhaps you can adapt it for R.